# What does this MessageSecurityException mean?

Tags: wcf, security, ntlm

Is this exception telling me that I'm calling a webservice that requires NTLM?

**Exception**

[MessageSecurityException: The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Negotiate'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm="bca-pdm-live.int.somecompany.ca",Negotiate,NTLM'.]
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg) +10259322
   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type) +539

If so, I have set the following security configuration to use NTLM yet i still get this exception.

```
<security mode="Transport">
    <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />           
</security>
```

How do i properly configure my client so I wouldn't get the exception above?

Comment: The exception states that the server is able to do Basic or Windows (both NTLM and Kerberos) authentication. Your client seems to try to use Kerberos. Are both in the same Windows domain, and do the client credentials give access to the service? Can you provide a larger part of your client and server side configuration file?